# MySQL Swedish Collation and 'é'

Tags: mysql, internationalization, collation

I've got a MySQL database that stores Swedish characters (not part of the PK, though) and does selects on those characters.

I don't have a ton of experience with this kind of stuff, but I had previously set the collation to "utf16_swedish_ci", which seems to have worked fine for a long time and was able to differentiate the similar characters (like ä vs a and é vs e) in select statements.

Lately, though, I noticed that using that collation seems to always consider é and e the same (though it seems to distinguish all of the other similar Swedish characters fine).

Did something change regarding that in newer versions of MySQL?  Or should that have always been the case and I just didn't notice it until now?  What collation should I be using to uniquely identify all the Swedish characters that won't have any weird side effects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`å`, `ä` and `ö` are part of the native Swedish alphabet, and don't need any special treatment. However, `é` is not native, and relies on accent rules for collation.

As far as I am aware, to get accent sensitive collation in `MySQL`, you need to use one of the binary collations - eg `utf16_bin`, which unfortunately also is case sensitive.

What version of `MySQL` are you using, and have you recently updated to a newer version? If you have, then rolling back to a previous version could solve your collation issues. I know there were some changes to the collations included in version 8.x.x, so maybe that is what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The MySQL server I'm using is on a hosted environment that I don't have much control over versioning on, but I'll see if I can determine the current version and if it was updated recently.

Comment: `SELECT @@version;`

Answer (score 1):

In most (including `swedish_ci`) utf8 or utf8mb4 collations `E`=`é`.  Exceptions:  `_bin` and `_icelandic_ci`.   See http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html and http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

Note that most collations end with `_ci`, which implies *both* case folding *and* (mostly) ignoring accents.

Do not use utf16 or utf32; use only utf8/utf8mb4.

MySQL has no collations that treat case and accent differently.

The only incompatible change in collations has been in 5.0 with the German `ß`.  It was a fiasco; MySQL will never change a collation again -- though it may add new collations.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So, if I understand correctly, the only option I have to distinguish accented characters is to use a _bin collation and then deal with case sensitivity?

Comment: @PAULUS - The latest 8.0 version has some `_as_ci` collations.  Upgrade and see if those are satisfactory for your application.